# Query needs optimizing, can anyone help?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT tmp.question_set_id,
       qs.sort_order, qa.type, qa.entities, qa.segment, qa.number_entities, qa.display,
       q.content, qa.value, m.title as media_title, m.content as media_content 
FROM question_set_answer qsa 
LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT * FROM question_set_answer ORDER BY RAND()) tmp ON (qsa.id= tmp.id) 
JOIN question_set qs ON qs.id = tmp.question_set_id 
JOIN question_answer qa ON qa.id = tmp.question_answer_id 
JOIN question q ON q.id = qa.question_id 
LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT component_id, title, content FROM media WHERE component ='question_answer') 
        m ON m.component_id = tmp.question_answer_id 
        WHERE qs.component_id = 142 
        AND qs.component = 'game_level' 
GROUP BY tmp.question_set_id 
ORDER BY qsa.id
```

Comment: Looks like you want Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/ no the IT Security site.

Comment: Welcome! Sometime in the next few minutes your question will be moved to StackOverflow. That site is dedicating to programming questions, which we consider this to fall under. You should familiarize yourself with the difference between some of the sites, and also with the formatting. In this case, I added four spaces to the start of each line to signify that your code was code, and should be formatted as such.

Comment: Also, you've given us no descriptions of what all those tables are... you have a lot of similarly named tables that are being joined together, and there are few of us who want to sit down and diagram your query out in order to understand it. You should give some background about your question. Some things to mention are what the tables are, how they relate, why you have subqueries ordered by rand(), and what it is you're trying to gain beyond "OPTIMIZE!"

Answer (score 0):

> `(SELECT * FROM question_set_answer ORDER BY RAND())`

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!

***AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!***

*ahem*  Sorry, lost my composure there.

`ORDER BY RAND()` means that the *entire table* has to be scanned and sorted.  Even if the entire rest of your query hit every single index properly, this would be your bottleneck if the table had any significant volume of data.  Judging from the fact that you asked this question, I'm wagering that you're having performance issues.

Other than this general bit of advice, can you please post the output of an [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) for that query?